# How to call expire_fragment from Rails Observer/Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached

I've pretty much tried everything, but it seems impossible to use 
expire_fragment from models?  I know you're not supposed to and it's 
non-MVC, but surely there much be some way to do it.

I created a module in lib/cache_helper.rb with all my expire helpers, 
within each are just a bunch of expire_fragment calls.  I have all my 
cache sweepers setup under /app/sweepers and have an "include 
CacheHelper" in my application controller so expiring cache within the 
app when called via controllers works fine.

Then things is I have some external daemons and especially some 
recurring cron tasks which call a rake task that calls a certain 
method.  This method does some processing and inputs entries into the 
model, after which I need to expire cache.

What's the best way to do this as I can't specify cache sweeper within the model. 
Straight up observers seem to be the best solution but then it 
complains about expire_fragment being undefined etc etc, I've even 
tried including the ActionController caching classes into the observer 
but that didn't work.  I'd love some ideas of how to create a solution 
for this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Disclaimer: My rails is a bit rusty, but this or something like it should work

```
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(key, options = nil)
```

Comment: Did anyone try this? I don't have rails handy but I'm pretty sure it will solve the problem...

Comment: I tried this in Rails 3.0.0.rc and it works great, thanks! It doesn't remove the folder hierarchy in the /tmp/cache directory but it does remove the cache file and that's what it needs to do.

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 2.3 - maybe due to a plugin. It says "NoMethodError (undefined method `rewrite' for nil:NilClass)" when executing the above line from within a sweeper. The call to a "rewrite" method is out of my scope - my application does not define such a function - neither do any plugins I'm using.

Comment: I get the following error in Rails 3.1 rc4: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'host' for nil:NilClass from "actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb:30:in 'url_options'".` I would guess that the request object is missing from the new controller instance. Suggestions?

Comment: Works like a charm here on rails 3.1.1, ruby 1.9.2-p290

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If this doesn't work for you too try Rails.cache.delete_‌​matched 'views/site_search_f‌​orm*'

Answer (score 13):

The solution provided by Orion works perfectly. As an enhancement and for convenience, I've put the following code into `config/initializers/active_record_expire_fragment.rb`

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def expire_fragment(*args)
    ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(*args)
  end
end
```

Now, you can use expire_fragment on all instances of ActiveRecord::Base, e.g. `User.first.expire_fragment('user-stats')`

Comment: This is the smoothest way to do this imho, have done similiar things with different helpers very often

Answer (score 8):

This is quite easy to do.  You can implement Orion's suggestion, but you can also implement the broader technique illustrated below, which gives you access to the current controller from any model and for whichever purpose you decided to break MVC separation for (e.g. messing with the fragment cache, accessing `current_user`, generating paths/URLs, etc.)

**In order to gain access to *the current request's controller* (if any) from *any* model**, add the following to `environment.rb` or, much preferably, to a new plugin (e.g. create `vendor/plugins/controller_from_model/init.rb` containing the code below):

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    protected
      def self.thread_safe_current_controller #:nodoc:
        Thread.current[:current_controller]
      end

      def self.thread_safe_current_controller=(controller) #:nodoc:
        Thread.current[:current_controller] = controller
      end

      # pick up the correct current_controller version
      #  from @@allow_concurrency
      if @@allow_concurrency
        alias_method :current_controller,  :thread_safe_current_controller
        alias_method :current_controller=, :thread_safe_current_controller=
      else
        cattr_accessor :current_controller
      end
  end
end
```

Then, in `app/controllers/application.rb`,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter { |controller|
    # all models in this thread/process refer to this controller
    #  while processing this request
    ActiveRecord::Base.current_controller = controller
  }

  ...
```

Then, **from any model**,

```
if controller = ActiveRecord::Base.current_controller
  # called from within a user request
else
  # no controller is available, didn't get here from a request - maybe irb?
fi
```

Anyhow, in your particular case you might want to inject code into your various `ActiveRecord::Base` descendants when the relevant controller classes load, so that the actual controller-aware code still resides in `app/controllers/*.rb`, but it is not mandatory to do so in order to get something functional (though ugly and hard to maintain.)

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for this!  In order to get it to work, I had to put the code into environment.rb (it did not work in a plugin) and change @@allow_concurrency to ActionController::Base.allow_concurrency (which I hope is the same thing).

Comment: Let the foot-shooting commence!

Answer (score 6):

In one of my scripts I use the following hack:

```
  require 'action_controller/test_process'

  sweepers = [ApartmentSweeper]

  ActiveRecord::Base.observers = sweepers
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers

  controller = ActionController::Base.new
  controller.request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
  controller.instance_eval do
    @url = ActionController::UrlRewriter.new(request, {})
  end

  sweepers.each do |sweeper|
    sweeper.instance.controller = controller
  end
```

Then, once the ActiveRecord callbacks are called, sweepers are able to call expire_fragment.

Comment: Maurycy,

Thanks for the example and snippet, I'll give this a shot.

Is this something I can just stick in a model?

Comment: This is a great trick, and I wouldn't call it a hack. You're setting up just enough state for the sweeper to do its job and letting everything else work as it normally does.

Comment: As a side note: I needed to replace "controller.request = ActionController::TestRequest.new" with "controller.request = request", otherwise the sweeper would try to expire caches for non-existent hosts. The "request" object is luckily available through a sweeper.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit of a rails noob, so this may not be correct, or even helpful, but it seems wrong to be trying to call controller actions from within the model.

Is it not possible to write an action within the controller that does what you want and then invoke the controller action from within your rake task?

Comment: If you are modifying database records from outside of a controller, you need to invalidate the cached views somehow, e.g. when a cron job imports data into your database. Rails is missing some important glue here. A cache sweeper only runs upon running an action on a controller. What about "actions" taken outside of controllers, i.e. background jobs? It should be possible to attach sweepers here, too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not have your external rake tasks call the expiry method on the controller.  Then you're still being MVC compliant, you aren't building in a dependence on some scoping hack, etc.

For that matter, why don't you just put all the daemon / external functionality on a controller and have rake / cron just call that.  It would be loads easier to maintain.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: This is somewhat funny, but not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Will it not be easier and clean just to pass the current controller as an argument to the model method call? Like following:

```
def delete_cascade(controller)

  self.categories.each do |c|
    c.delete_cascade(controller)
    controller.expire_fragment(%r{article_manager/list/#{c.id}.*})                
  end
  PtSection.delete(self.id)
  controller.expire_fragment(%r{category_manager/list/#{self.id}.*})        
end
```

You can access all public methods and properties of the controller from within model. 
As long as you do not modify the state of the controller, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might not work for what you're doing, but you may be able to define a custom call back on your model:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    define_callback :after_exploded

    def explode
        ... do something that invalidates your cache ...
        callback :after_exploded
    end
end
```

You can then use a sweeper like you would normally:

```
class SomeModelSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe SomeModel 

    def after_exploded(model)
      ... expire your cache
    end
end
```

Let me know if this is useful!