# Manually Clear Fragment Cache in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I'm using Memcached with Heroku for a Rails 3.1 app.  I had a bug and the wrong things are showing - the parameters were incorrect for the cache.

I had this:

```
<% cache("foo_header_cache_#{@user.id}") do %>
```

I removed the fragment caching and pushed to Heroku and the bad data went away.

And then I changed it to:

```
<% cache("foo_header_cache_#{@foo.id}") do %>
```

However, when I corrected the parameters, from @user to @foo, the old [incorrect] cached version showed again (instead of refreshing with the correct data).

How can I manually expire this, or otherwise get rid of this bad data that is showing?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I ended up manually clearing the entire cache by going into the rails console and using the command:

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

Comment: John Kloian's answer allows you to expire a single fragment. If you have a site that gets a fair amount of traffic and relies on caching, expiring everything could result in very slow page loads or timeout errors as the cache is warmed.

Answer (score 30):

From the rails console:

```
Rails.cache.delete 'FRAGMENT-NAME'
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer. The accepted one is using a shotgun to kill a fly.

Comment: That's what works for me for expiring a fragment cache in Rails 4.2: `Rails.cache.delete(['views', 'FRAGMENT-NAME'])`

Answer (score 22):

Here you are:

```
<% ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("foo_header_cache_#{@user.id}") %>
```

Reference:
- [How to call expire_fragment from Rails Observer/Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393395/how-to-call-expire-fragment-from-rails-observer-model)

Answer (score 12):

**From the console:**

You can run this (ie. if you know the id is '1')

```
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("foo_header_cache_1")
```

To use `Rails.cache.delete` you need to know the fragment name.  In your case, it would be

```
Rails.cache.delete("views/foo_header_cache_1") # Just add 'views/' to the front of the string
```

If you have an array-based cache key using objects, such as:

```
cache([:foo_header_cache, @user])
```

Then you can get the fragment name like so

```
ActionController::Base.new.fragment_cache_key([:foo_header_cache, @user])
```

The name includes the `id` and `updated_at` time from any objects (to the yyyymmddhhmmss).  It would be something like "views/foo_header_cache/users/1-20160901021000"

Or simply clear it using the array.

```
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment([:foo_header_cache, @user])
```

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer. 
After many uses I figured this is a bit cleaner to use instead of calling the ActionController module:
`Rails.cache.clear(['views', :foo_header_cache, @user])` (works in Rails 4.2 at least)