# How to remove all data chrome stores for a url?

Tags: google-chrome

**TL;DR** I'd like to make chrome's state as though it had never, ever visited a certain url before.

Longer version:

I'm working on an application, and have a [complicated problem regarding XSS vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63911493/5783745), which *could* be caused by the browser 'remembering' something about a previous session which could cause nonces to not match. The upshot is that I need to be absolutely sure that when I visit the app url that chrome hasn't 'remembered' anything about it from any previous session(s).

Here's what I've tried:

- Firstly, visiting: `chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=example.com` and deleting all the cookies
- Secondly, visiting: `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and deleting everything (unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible for one url at a time?)

I can prove that chrome has not completely 'forgotten' the site. The proof is complicated, but basically if I place a different app (with different flavicon) at the url, visit the url, then close out that tab, then complete the steps above to clear browser data and cookies (at this point chrome *should* have forgotten everything). Yet when I put a different app at the same url and visit the url, chrome uses the **old** app's flavicon, which (I think) proves that it hasn't completely forgotten everything it knew about the url!

So, that's the long version. But, the TL;DR is to simply make it as though chrome had never visited a site (preferably without altering data stored for other sites, or doing anything extreme like completely uninstalling/reinstalling)

#### A third attempt

To empty cache and hard reload, press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to bring up the developer console, then right click on refresh and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. Yet the old flavicon *still* remains, indicating that not all info from that site was removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After about 2 hours, I figured the following techniques to try to remove the flavicon, but **even after all of the following steps, as the flavicon from a previous app still remains in Chrome's 'memory'**!

Do the first two steps from the question:

1. visit: `chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=example.com` and delete all the cookies (replace example.com with the url in question)
2. visit: `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and deleting everything (would be great to know how to do this for a single site)
3. **Right click** on the tiny icon to the immediate left of the url (it will be a lock if using https, or the letter 'i' if using http).
4. Go into each of categories listed (e.g. 'Cookies', 'Site Settings' etc) and delete them all

[image]

#### Note

I didn't find a solution for removing all data from chrome, however, I found you can start a completely isolated chrome session with [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235351/5783745) instructions

Comment: Possible solution (for flavicon) [here](https://www.nullalo.com/en/how-to-delete-google-chrome-favicon-cache/)