# Rails Fragment Cache Won't Expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I'm using fragment caching in my 3.1. Rails app and have one fragment that isn't expiring and I don't know why.  It's a fragment that I want to expire based on time (every hour).  I'm on Heroku, using the Memcachier Add-on for my caching.  I don't seem to have any other caching issues.

In my app, there are three models: User, Community, and Activity.  On the Community#index, there is a fragment that shows Activity by Users in this Community that I want to expire hourly.  The calculation, which is a method in the Activity model, works fine - it's just that the fragment is expiring hourly (and refreshing).

In my view, I have:

```
<% cache("activity_#{community.id}", :expires_in => 1.hour) do %>               
    <-- content >      
<% end %>
```

I've also tried making it a scheduled task, by adding an expiration for the cache in the User model.

```
  def self.expire_activity
    Community.find_each do |community|
      ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment('activity_#{community.id}')
    end
  end
```

I tried to follow the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393395/how-to-call-expire-fragment-from-rails-observer-model) to determine how to expire the cache from a model, but with this this code, I get the error:

`NoMethodError: undefine method 'expire_fragment' for #<Class:0x5ffc3e8>`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue on Rails 4.2.1. It was caused by a mismatch between the servers set timezone and that of the rails app. Setting both to be the same fixed my issue.

On the server, assuming Ubuntu, as root run this command and follow the prompts:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Within the `application.rb` config file, be sure that the following line matches the server (default is UTC).

```
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

To get a list of available time zones for rails, run:

```
bundle exec rake time:zones:all
```

I know this is an old question, but is returned high up in google when searching for a solution.